# Laravel ajax form call jQuery function

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm starting to learn Laravel, first time and first project.

I have my custom login form working, but want to improve it, ajax request works fine, but can't call a JS function. The documentation of the template I'm using says to trigger with JS.

[image: documentation]

I've tried calling the function directly:

```
error: function() { // What to do if we fail
    One.helpers('notify', {type: 'danger', icon: 'fa fa-times mr-1', message: 'Your message!'});
}
```

Also tried to call with jQuery.trigger:

```
error: function() { // What to do if we fail
    jQuery.trigger(One.helpers('notify', {type: 'danger', icon: 'fa fa-times mr-1', message: 'Your message!'}););
}
```

Nothing seems to work.

Ajax Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /**
         * @return {boolean}
         */
        function LoginUser()
        {
            var formData = {
                username: $("input[name=login-username]").val(),
                password: $("input[name=login-password]").val()
            };

            // Ajax Post
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type: "post",
                url: "/login",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                success: function(){ // What to do if we succeed

                },
                error: function() { // What to do if we fail

                }
            });

            return false;
        }
</script>
```

What I expected is a notification message like this:

[image: notification message]

What I get:

> Absolutely nothing, nothing shows up on the page.

Laravel Routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    }

    return view('auth.login');
});

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\LoginMiddleware'], function () {
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/dashboard/', 'HomeController@dashboard');
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/admin/users', 'HomeController@admin_users');
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/admin/permissions', 'HomeController@admin_permissions');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

Comment: What url is producing the error? Also, please my show the contents of `LoginMiddleware`.

Comment: Possibly your ajax call is calling the incorrect url. Could you check the network tab of your browser and compare the url with the routes that are returned with the Artisan command `php artisan route:list`. Something that stands out is that you are adding the route in your web routes file which, as shown in comments at the top of the file, have the web middleware by [default](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#basic-routing).

Comment: The error no longer happens, but I can't still show the notification...

Answer (score 0):

make sure you didn't miss the csrf meta tag in html head:

```
<head>
    ...
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    ....
</head>
```

or you can simply replace the `{{ csrf_token() }}` with `$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')` in your code, like this:

```
// Ajax Post
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    },
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Everything is in place, the error is only triggered when I try to call the notification message, if a put there e console.log or alert no error triggered.

Comment: @Karbust this is nothing to do with laravel, it's an issue with the One library that you are using in the client side.  add more details please. where can i find the documentation?

Comment: I was able to solve it, aparently they forgot to mention that I had to download the Notify plugin and include it, that's why the functions weren't recognized and nothing happened.

Answer (score -1):

U get this error, because route "login" cant accept "POST" request.
try change `type: "post",` to `type: "get",`, u should get something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /**
         * @return {boolean}
         */
        function LoginUser()
        {
            var formData = {
                username: $("input[name=login-username]").val(),
                password: $("input[name=login-password]").val()
            };

            // Ajax Post
            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                type: "get",
                url: "/login",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                success: function(){ // What to do if we succeed

                },
                error: function() { // What to do if we fail

                }
            });

            return false;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Everything works fine with POST (and I would never send username and password through GET), except when I try to use the notification message the error message is triggered, otherwise works...

Comment: Can u show routes file (routes/web.php and routes/api.php) in laravel ?

Comment: Add to the first post

Comment: other route files ex.: "routes/api.php" is empty?

Comment: Only this on api.php: Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Comment: This is the example in the documentation: https://i.imgur.com/X2OG1B7.png